# Simplejson decoding error only occurs when performing over two iterations

Tags: python, json

I'm trying to use the names module along with a wrapper for temp-mail.org (https://github.com/saippuakauppias/temp-mail) for part of a project involving creating temporary email addresses. My code is as shown below and works fine unless n is greater than 2.

```
import names
from random import randint
from tempmail import TempMail

n = input("Please enter number of email addresses: ")
i = 0
while i < n:
    first = names.get_first_name()
    second = names.get_last_name()
    tm = TempMail(login= first + "." + second + str(randint(1,99)))
    email = tm.get_email_address()
    print email
    i = i+1
```

If n is greater than two the loop will execute twice then I receive the following error:

```
>>> runfile('/root/voter.py', wdir='/root')
Please enter number of email addresses: 3
Randell.Elkin17@stexsy.com
Michael.Martinez6@stexsy.com
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/spyderlib/widgets/externalshell/sitecustomize.py", line 714, in runfile
    execfile(filename, namespace)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/spyderlib/widgets/externalshell/sitecustomize.py", line 81, in execfile
    builtins.execfile(filename, *where)
  File "/root/voter.py", line 12, in <module>
    email = tm.get_email_address()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tempmail.py", line 66, in get_email_address
    available_domains = self.available_domains
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tempmail.py", line 36, in available_domains
    domains = req.json()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/requests/models.py", line 826, in json
    return complexjson.loads(self.text, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/simplejson/__init__.py", line 516, in loads
    return _default_decoder.decode(s)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/simplejson/decoder.py", line 370, in decode
    obj, end = self.raw_decode(s)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/simplejson/decoder.py", line 400, in raw_decode
    return self.scan_once(s, idx=_w(s, idx).end())
simplejson.scanner.JSONDecodeError: Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0)
```

I know this is a longshot as the tempmail module isn't widely used however I was hoping I've made a simple error elsewhere and someone could help? Thanks

Comment: I imagine this is an issue with `TempMail` trying to fetch the list of available domains from `api.temp-mail.ru` and failing, possibly due to too many requests at once or something.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay so I looked over your problem.

The package [temp-mail](https://github.com/saippuakauppias/temp-mail) seems to make a request to temp-mail.ru *each* time you call `TempMail()` to get a list of available domains.

You are encountering the API's [rate limiting](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rate_limiting) (in short, you are calling the API too many times in a too short window)

I added some debug to the package to see what was happening. I created a [virtualenv](https://virtualenv.pypa.io/en/stable/) to test your code. This makes modules that I install (`temp-mail` and `names` only local to the project and not globally installed on the system) and looked at the stacktrace. The line that calls the json part is `domains = req.json()`, located at `/home/arch/tmp-tempmail/env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tempmail.py`.

I then edited the file to add some prints (you have to have some notions about the [request](https://github.com/kennethreitz/requests) module first):

```
url = 'http://{0}/request/domains/format/json/'.format(
    self.api_domain)
req = requests.get(url)
print req
print req.text
domains = req.json()
```

The output is:

```
Please enter number of email addresses: 3
<Response [200]>
["@stexsy.com"]
Larry.Gerald20@stexsy.com
<Response [200]>
["@stexsy.com"]
Darlene.Bullock32@stexsy.com
<Response [429]>

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "main.py", line 29, in <module>
    email = tm.get_email_address()
  File "/home/arch/tmp-tempmail/env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tempmail.py", line 68, in get_email_address
    available_domains = self.available_domains
  File "/home/arch/tmp-tempmail/env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tempmail.py", line 38, in available_domains
    domains = req.json()
  File "/home/arch/tmp-tempmail/env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/requests/models.py", line 826, in json
    return complexjson.loads(self.text, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/json/__init__.py", line 319, in loads
    return _default_decoder.decode(s)
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/json/decoder.py", line 339, in decode
    obj, end = self.raw_decode(s, idx=_w(s, 0).end())
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/json/decoder.py", line 357, in raw_decode
    raise JSONDecodeError("Expecting value", s, err.value) from None
json.decoder.JSONDecodeError: Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0)
```

You can see that at the response that fails is the third one and it has the HTTP error code 429 which translates to "Too Many Requests".
The JSON parser crashes just because the input is empty.

On the other hand, the API's [docs](https://temp-mail.org/en/api/) says:

> You can generate absolutely any email address without API notification

So if you have the domain, you don't need to make a request to the server for receiving mails on the server.

You could also add a delay inside the loop.

```
import names
from random import randint
from tempmail import TempMail
import time

n = input("Please enter number of email addresses: ")
i = 0
while i < n:
    first = names.get_first_name()
    second = names.get_last_name()
    tm = TempMail(login= first + "." + second + str(randint(1,99)))
    email = tm.get_email_address()
    print email
    time.sleep(1)
    i = i+1
```

Comment: Perfect, thanks for explaining rather than just adding the delay! What did you add to view the HTTP responses?

Comment: @RyanFirth I updated my answer. Please upvote my answer if you found it helpful ;)

Comment: Brilliant, thanks; upvoted but as I have less than 15 reputation at the moment it's only recorded not displayed!

Comment: Yikes, forgot about that ;) Anyway I upvoted you so you're on the way!